# Cannot create an instance of class com.example.sewinglessons.SewingViewModel

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Every time I try to run my app on my device, it crashes and I get this error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sewinglessons, PID: 10153                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.sewinglessons.SewingViewModel                                                                                                      at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)

This is my code:

SewingViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.sewinglessons

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.sewinglessons.domain.GetPatternByIdUseCase
import com.example.sewinglessons.domain.GetPatternsUseCase
import com.example.sewinglessons.domain.items.SewingItem
import com.example.sewinglessons.domain.items.SpecificPatternItem
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.lang.Exception
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class SewingViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getPatternsUseCase: GetPatternsUseCase,
    private val getPatternByIdUseCase: GetPatternByIdUseCase
    ) : ViewModel() {

    private val _patterns = MutableLiveData<List<SewingItem>>()
    val patterns: LiveData<List<SewingItem>> get() = _patterns

    private val _pattern = MutableLiveData<SpecificPatternItem>()
    val pattern: LiveData<SpecificPatternItem> get() = _pattern

    init {
        getPatterns()
    }

    private fun getPatterns() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val patterns = getPatternsUseCase()
                _patterns.value = patterns
            } catch (_: Exception) {}
        }
    }

    fun getPatternById(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val pattern = getPatternByIdUseCase(id)
                _pattern.value = pattern
            } catch (_: Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeScreen.kt

```
package com.example.sewinglessons.screens

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import coil.compose.rememberImagePainter
import com.example.sewinglessons.HomeViewModel
import com.example.sewinglessons.components.AppToolbar
import com.example.sewinglessons.R
import com.example.sewinglessons.components.AppBottomNavigation
import com.example.sewinglessons.domain.items.SewingItem
import com.example.sewinglessons.navigation.Screen
import com.example.sewinglessons.SewingViewModel

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(), sewingViewModel: SewingViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Scaffold (
        topBar = {
            AppToolbar(toolbarTitle = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                logoutButtonClicked = {
                    homeViewModel.logout()
                })
        },
        bottomBar = {
            AppBottomNavigation(
                selectedTab = Screen.HomeScreen,
                onTabSelected = { /* Handle tab selection */ }
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Surface (
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimary))
                .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                val patterns = sewingViewModel.patterns.observeAsState(listOf()).value

                LazyColumn {
                    items(patterns) { pattern ->
                        SewingCard(pattern = pattern)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SewingCard (pattern: SewingItem) {
    Card(
        elevation = 7.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 7.dp, bottom = 7.dp, start = 14.dp, end = 14.dp)
            .clickable {
            }
    ) {
        Row {
            Image(painter= rememberImagePainter(pattern.image),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(175.dp)
                    .height(115.dp)
            )
            Column (modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)) {
                Text(text = pattern.name, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(text = pattern.short_description, maxLines = 2, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    HomeScreen()
}
```

Comment: can u please post how you pass your `viewmodel` to `HomeScreen`

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't annotate your `MainActivity` with `@AndroidEntryPoint` in which `HomeScreen` composable is called because this annotation is required to use `viewModels()` or `viewModel()` function in composables. Here how you can do it:

**Step 1:** Annotate activity class in which the `HomeScreen` composable is called.

```
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    //...
}
```

**Step 2:** Annotate your application class with `@HiltAndroidApp` otherwise previous step  will end up with error.

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication: Application() {
    //...
}
```

**Step 3:** Don't forgot to add `MyApplication` class in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication">
        <!-- ... -->
</application>
```